# How to get records with first letter that match one of three letters

Tags: mysql

I would like to retrieve records who's first letter match either a, b or c. They should match whether they are caps or not.

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title from tblName WHERE  first letter of title in (a, b, c) order by title ASC";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SELECT id, title from tblName where
>   title REGEXP '^[abc]' order by title
>   ASC